# how to get all the id's of posts made under specific category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get all the ID's of posts which I have made in a specific category.

I have created a category in WordPress e.g `web-articals`.

I have created some posts and linked those with `web-articals` category. 
Now I want to display the content of post whichI have created inside that category and for that I want all the post ID's inside that category.

How can I get ID's off all the post inside of web-articals category?

```
<?php

query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'web articals', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => ASC  ) );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </li> 
      <?php
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

I have tried this but dis way of doing it but dis dispalys only the title of the posts in unordered list:
e.g

- Frame Work   <----- these are my post titles
- Open Source
- Model–View–Controller (MVC)

but i want somthing which look like

- Frame Work

"content of my post  frame works"

- Open Source

" content ofmy post Open Source"

- Model–View–Controller (MVC)

"content of my post"

Comment: FYI, you misspelled "articles".

Comment: ohh leave tht dude tht was jst speling mistake .. it's not a key word of wordpress or php ... it's jst a category i have created. i'll correct it later jst suggest me a way of doin' it

Comment: All of them: "articals" should be "articles". "artical" isn't an English word.

Comment: thanks alot for teaching me english .. i'd be grateful if u post a piece of a code which will solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below are the posts of web articals

```
Frame Work <----- these are my post titles
Open Source
Model–View–Controller (MVC)
```

If it is so, then use [`the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) function like you have used `the_title();`.

Answer (score 2):

it works guys here i leave ans for some1 to get help from it.

```
    <?php

query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'web articals', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => ASC  ) );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <!--echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';-->
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php echo get_post_field('post_content',  the_ID());

 ?>
      </li> 
      <?php
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

thanks huys for help